# Compile Error While using JSP comments?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

Am using JSP in my webpage but the following code returns the following compile error.

```
An error occurred at line: 27 in the jsp file: /login.jsp
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
24:     con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:base","root","root"); 
25:  
26:     String username= request.getParameter("uname");  
27:     String password= request.getParameter("pass");   <%-- Getting the password   entered by the user --%>
28:     String query = "SELECT * FROM users where uname=? AND pass=?";  
29:     stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
30:     stmt.setString(1,username);
```

But the code works just fine after deleting the comments on line 27.

The whole code is:

```
<%
try{
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");                      

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:base","root","root"); 

    String username= request.getParameter("uname");  
    String password= request.getParameter("pass");   //Getting the password entered by the user
    String query = "SELECT * FROM users where uname=? AND pass=?";  
    stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
    stmt.setString(1,username);
    stmt.setString(2,password);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    session.setAttribute("name",username);   
    if(rs.next())                               
    {   
        response.sendRedirect("Sitelogin.jsp"); 
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     out.println(e);
}
finally
{

}
```

%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use JSP comments inside scriptlets `<% ... %>`.

JSPs are compiled into Java servlet classes.  The content of a scriptlet is written straight into the servlet class.  As `<%-- ... --%>` isn't valid Java code, you get a compiler error.

Inside scriptlets, use the usual Java comments `// ...`  and `/* ... */`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are already inside a scriptlet, you don't need to comment with the JSP-way. Inside scriptlets, all you code should look exactly how it is done in any java source file.

```
<%
    try{
        Connection con=null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");                      

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:base","root","root"); 

        String username= request.getParameter("uname");  
        String password= request.getParameter("pass");   //Getting the password entered by the user
        String query = "SELECT * FROM users where uname=? AND pass=?";  
        stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1,username);
        stmt.setString(2,password);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        session.setAttribute("name",username);   
        if(rs.next())                               
        {   
            response.sendRedirect("Sitelogin.jsp"); 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         out.println(e);
    }
    finally
    {

    }
%>
```